# Scripting - Value Types - how to approach this?

Tags: c++

I am writing my own scripting language and need to handle value types somehow.

I need to define a variable values in my script like in the snippet below

```
#Var #Name="Alpha" #Class="Float" #Value=1.0
#Var #Name="Beta" #Class="Int" #Value=1
#Var #Name="Delta" #Class="Vector2" #Value=(1.0,2.0)
#Var #Name="Echo" #Class="String" #Value="abcdefgh"
```

As you can see, each #Var has a #Class defining what **type** of value to expect.

The problem is i don't know how to approach it 'easily' so that i can manage the values later on in a simple manner:

```
float fAlpha = GetVar("Alpha")->GetValue();
fAlpha = 150.0f;
GetVar("Alpha")->SetValue(fAlpha);
```

...

```
CVector2 vDelta = GetVar("Delta")->GetValue();
vDelta=CVector2(10.0,20.0);
GetVar("Delta")->SetValue(vDelta)
```

I can check for #Var #Class all over the time, but i am looking for something more clear/OO.

```
if(GetVar("Alpha")->GetClass() == "Float")
{
float fAlpha = GetVar("Alpha")->GetValue();
}
```

Can somebody shed a bit of light on how do you approach this ?

Thanks.

Comment: @g-makulik, take it easy..

Comment: OoooK, what about putting the `Class` instances into a `std::map<std::string,ClassHandler>` and use templated types for easier extensibility? Boost libraries also offer a mechanism (see `boost::any`) that might be useful for this, have a look for usage in the `boost::program_options` library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've handled this in the past was with inheritance and virtual functions:

When creating a variable, I do something like this:

```
variable_base *var = new variable_int;
```

which is implemented something like this:

```
class variable_base {
public:
    virtual ~variable_base() {}

public:
    virtual variable_base *clone() const = 0;

public:
    // all operations you can do to a variable as pure virtual functions here
    virtual variable_base *operator+=(const variable_base *rhs) = 0;
    // ...
};

class variable_int : public variable_base {
public:
    virtual variable_base *clone() const { return new variable_int(*this); }

public
    virtual variable_base *operator+=(const variable_base *rhs) {
        if(variable_int *other = dynamic_cast<variable_int *>(rhs)) {
            // int += int
            value_ += other->value_;
        } else {
            // throw exception, or convert, whatever you want
        }
        return this;
    }

private:
    int value_;
};
```

and I would do this for each possible variable type.

The only time it gets tricky is when an operation should "up-convert" the l-value. For example, in my scripting language `char + string == string` in order to be consistent with `string + char == string`

Comment: I was thinking about the same approach but postponed it as it seems like i need to check for the class of the variable everywhere i am going to use it.

So before actually setting the value on the VAR i need to check it's class ant cast a correc type on it. Am i right?

Comment: Well that's what the virtual functions are for. You implement the checks in the operations for each type. But the higher level code doesn't need to care.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently.
I stored every variable as a [void pointer](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/613-void-pointers/) and then when I wanted to access the value I would just pass the void pointer and the value I wanted to set it to.

I had overloaded four or so functions, one for each variable type, but all with the same name.

```
setValue(&currentVoidPointerToVar , string("value") )
```

The correct function (in this case, the string one) would then check the type of variable stored at the void pointer. If it matches the specified value it would recast the void pointer into the correct type, then access this object, then set the value.

Answer (score 0):

The [`boost::program_options` library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/program_options.html) basically does something similar. You register the type of known options and retrieve values using [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/any.html).

You could discriminate the value extraction using your known `#Class` strings providing appropriate handlers (e.g. functors).